# Algorithm for ArKit3, BodyTracking

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, arkit

Do any of you know the standard algo. that's being used behind the apis for BodyTracking?

I know the stuff is written on Metal2, and the true-depth uses Viola-Jones for facial recognition, but are the algos behind the ARKit exposed?